# Difference between 'const ref' and 'in'?

Tags: d

I'm trying to understand the difference between `const ref` and `in`, specially when it comes to performance.

1. I know that `in` is equivalent to `const scope`, but what does `the scope stor­age class means that ref­er­ences in the pa­ra­me­ter can­not be es­caped (e.g. as­signed to a global vari­able).` mean? example code is welcome.
2. How do I decide between `const ref` and `in` when implementing a function?  I know with `ref` the object doesn't get copied because it's a reference, but is the same true with `in`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) the `scope` parameter storage class means that you're not allowed to escape a reference to the parameter. Example:

```
Object glob;

struct S
{
    Object o;
    void foo(scope Object o)
    {
         this.o = o; // Not allowed! 'o' must not be escaped
         glob = o; // ditto
    }
}
```

Note that DMD is not very good at detecting this. The above example currently compiles, but is not allowed.

`scope` is most useful for delegate parameters:

```
void foo(scope void delegate() dg)
{
    /* use dg */
}

void main()
{
    int i;
    foo({ ++i; });
}
```

In the above example, no closure needs to be allocated for the anonymous function even though it has an upvalue, because `foo` "guarantees" (it is the compiler's job...) that the delegate isn't escaped. DMD currently does implement this optimization.

2) I think the idea is that when both `const` and `scope` is used, the compiler could theoretically pass by reference or value at will, which is why the `in` shortcut is useful. DMD doesn't take advantage of this right now, but it's a handy shortcut nevertheless, and it has some documentation value.

In short, `in` won't currently gain you any performance unless it's used on a delegate. `ref` *can* gain you some performance with large structs or static arrays. When `ref` is used for performance reasons, `const` is often used to document (and enforce) that the `ref` is **not** used to update the original value.

Comment: 1. good, that explains why I wasn't able to reproduce the effect. 2. so, are you saying that if a parameter of a function has `in` storage class, it gets copied? should I be using `const ref` then?

Comment: With the current compiler selection, all based on DMD, it does get copied. But the neat thing about it is that it's still technically implementation defined because the user cannot tell the difference. For DMD to take advantage of this for optimization, it needs to fully implement `scope` first. If you have identified the copying as a bottleneck and you want to optimize, using `const ref` is a good idea.

Comment: How do you know so much about DMD?  are you one of the core-devs?

Comment: Nah, but becoming familiar with the bugs and quirks of DMD is sadly necessary to use D to its full potential with the current restrictions and limitations, seeing as the two other usable compilers, GDC and LDC, also use the DMD front-end. I also follow the development closely on Github, the NewsGroup, and #d on FreeNode.

Comment: Two things of note. 1. The language spec would have to be changed to allow the compiler to pass an `in` parameter by `ref`. `in` is clearly defined as `const scope`, and changing that would be a breaking change to the ABI. `auto ref` is what's used if you want a function to be able to take either a `ref` or not (and it's a bit buggy at the moment IIRC). You may or may not be able to mix `auto ref` with `const`. I don't know. 2. A _huge_ difference between `in` and `const ref` which you don't cover at all is the fact that `const ref` must take an lvalue, whereas `in` doesn't have to.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis, as far as I can see, passing `in` parameters by reference would be an optimizer choice. The ABI only comes into the picture when the source of the function is not dealt with in the same call to DMD, such as when doing separate compilation or when using D interface files.

Comment: @jA_cOp The spec specifically says that `in` is the same as `const scope`, so it's _not_ a choice of the optimizer at this point, even if it theoretically could be. And just because an ABI change primarily affects stuff like shared libraries doesn't mean that it doesn't matter - especially since that sort of stuff affects the linking phase, which is _after_ all of the compilation (including optimizations) was done. It _could_ be that `in` will be changed at some point to be more flexible as you suggest, but it would require a spec change, so dmd _can't_ optimize it at this point.

Answer (score 11):

1. It's not legal for `scope` parameters to escape the function. The compiler is supposed to guarantee that no references to that data escape the function. It's used primarily with delegates, since it allows the compiler to avoid allocating a closure, since it knows that the delegate won't escape.
2. `const ref` is `const` - just like `in` would be - but the variable is passed by reference instead of being copied, so you avoid a copy. However, *unlike C++* `const ref` does *not* work with rvalues. It *must* be given an lvalue. So, if you declare a parameter to be `const ref`, it's going to be limiting in what you can pass to it. You'll generally have to declare a variable to pass to it, whereas `in` will accept a temporary.

   ```
   void func(const ref int var) {}
   int a;
   func(a); //legal
   func(7); //illegal
   ```

Both of those calls would be legal if `func` took `const` or `in`. So, in general, the question is not whether you should use `const ref` or `in`. The question is whether you should use `const` or `in`. And in that case, the question is whether you want to use `scope` or not, since they're both `const`. And you use `scope` if you want to ensure that no reference to variable that you pass in will escape that function, so it's generally only used with delegates but could be useful with classes or arrays.

However, `pure` on a function guarantees that no references to any of its arguments can escape except via the return value (since `pure` functions can only use global variables if they're immutable or are value types and are const), so `pure` generally gives you all that you need for parameters which are classes and arrays. In addition, if the return type is a class or array, you general don't want to make it so that the arguments can't escape, because then instead of being able to reuse anything from those arguments in the return value, the function is forced to make a copy, which is generally less efficient.

So, `scope` is generally only of use with delegates, but upon occasion is useful with classes or arrays. It's already generally preferable for functions to be `pure` anyway, so that takes care of most of the issue. As such, while it doesn't hurt to use `in`, there's often little point in using `in` instead of `const`. And you generally only use `const ref` if you really want to avoid copying the variable being passed in, because otherwise you can only pass lvalues to that function. You *can* overload a function such that it has version which takes `const` and one which takes `const ref`, but that obviously results in code duplication, so unless you really want `const ref`, it's probably just best to use `const`.

**EDIT:**

`scope` has yet to be implemented for anything other than delegates (as of 2013-06-18), so using either `scope` or `in` with anything other than delegates is ill-advised. At the moment, they're misleading, and if/once `scope` is implemented for anything other than delegates, there's a high risk that your code will break due to references to the variables marked with `scope` or `in` escaping.

Comment: Isn't it true that `in` doesn't quite work the way it should because `scope` isn't fully implemented in DMD?  Wouldn't it be a breaking change once `scope` is fully implemented for those who have used `in` incorrectly?

Comment: Assuming that `scope` is buggy (and it may very well be; I don't use it much, so I'm not exactly sure of its current state), then yes, it would be a breaking change for any code that used `scope` or `in` incorrectly, but that's the same with pretty much any compiler bug. Fortunately, the number of such issues in dmd has been dropping significantly due to the fast pace of development since moving to github, but it's certainly still possible to run into issues where a feature isn't implemented correctly.

Comment: `scope` isn't really buggy, it's just not implemented at all except for an optimization. `pure` is rarely a good alternative to `scope` because with a `pure` member function, you can still escape the parameter by assigning it to a member field, and `pure` has other, unrelated restrictions. If `scope` was fully implemented, it would be useful for a great number of cases, such as being able to safely pass slices to stack memory to a function receiving it with `scope`.

Comment: The uses for `scope` and `pure` are different, but in general, `pure` is plenty, and `scope` is overly restrictive. For instance, in most cases, you _want_ references to arrays to be able to escape, since otherwise you would have to dup them instead of slicing them. `pure` should generally be used unless you can't, whereas `scope` should generally only be used if a particular situation requires it.

Comment: I don't see how `scope` could be described as overly restrictive. You only use it when you don't need to escape references, for documentation purposes and optimization opportunities. It does one thing and one thing only. `pure` has an unrelated and much broader meaning. Yes, you should use `pure` whenever you can, but it has nothing to do with `scope`.

Comment: pure stops references from being set to global variables, so it avoids escaping as far as that goes. scope avoids it completely. So yes they're different but not totally unrelated. scope tends to be overly restrictive because you can't return any references to the data, and for arrays that's generally far too restrictive, since it disallows slicing, which forces the code to be far less efficient. So yes, if you want to guarantee that the data doesn't escape the function at all, then use scope, but at least as far as arrays go, that's needlessly inefficient and so isn't generally a good idea.