# The difference of 'in' and 'const' in D language

Tags: constants, d

Reading this tutorial: http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/function_parameters.html

I cannot understand the difference between `in` and `const`: **what is it?**

```
dchar lastLetter(const dchar[] str) {
    return str[$ - 1];
}

dchar lastLetter(in dchar[] str) {
    return str[$ - 1];
}
```

Comment: IIRC in also has the ref qualifier (avoiding a copy)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515579/difference-between-const-ref-and-in seems relevant. Not sure if it qualifies as a dup.

Comment: It actually *is* relevant. I remember that thread now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is nicely explained in the *D Language Reference* ( http://dlang.org/function.html#parameters ) section which describes parameter storage classes (off-topic items are omitted):

- **scope** : references in the parameter cannot be escaped (e.g. assigned to a global variable)
- **in** : equivalent to const scope
- **const** : argument is implicitly converted to a const type
- **ref** : parameter is passed by reference (implicit for reference types, see below)

When they think about parameter storage class, D programmers should remember that D has value (structs, unions, static arrays and PODs) and reference (dynamic arrays, classes) types. The first group of types is always passed by value, unless you use the **ref** parameter storage class which is going to tell D compiler to explicitly pass by reference. Reference types will naturally be passed by reference, so **ref** is implicit in this case.

Comment: Thank you, but I does `in` pass by copy?

Comment: Depends what is the argument.

Comment: If I write `in SampleStruct ss` will it be like `const ref SampleStruct ss` ?

Comment: No, `in` will not make it be passed by reference (assuming SampleStruct is a struct). It will be a `const scope`, considering that SampleStruct (if it is a struct, you did not specify) is a value type, it will be passed by value. If you want it to be passed by reference, then you must use `ref` parameter storage class (ie `const ref` or `auto ref`).

Comment: `SampleStruct` is a struct ;). Ok, I thought that `in` passes always by reference, since it's always described next to `ref` in tutorials...

Comment: Also be warned that `scope` is actually not implemented as documented and does nothing right now in most cases. So effective difference from `const` is only convention,